# UIButton with UIImage . changing the frame after setting the button's image to nil will not remove image

Tags: ios, uibutton

I can "fix" the problem with simple **if** and not changing the frame if there is no image..
but I want to make sure I'm not missing something.

I had a bug when the image in the button was not clear after setting it to nil, but it happen only in some cases.

After debugging I saw that if I change the frame after I set the image with nil, that Image still appear.

Is there a way to clear the image in the UIButton, that will clear the image no matter what ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this.

```
if[myButton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal]!=nil)
{
       [myButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: thanks.
also, for others :
to check if the image not exist :
if[self.myImageButton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal]==nil)